# Pyephem failing to install after "Cleanup" stage

Tags: pyephem

I ran pip install pyephem, and all text is white, then I get a white "Cleaning up...", followed by red text that reads

```
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-eG5Kab/pyephem/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-LWQvRn-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-eG5Kab/pyephem
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 248, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 40: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What do I need to do here?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out myself. Needed to use pip3 install pyephem instead, since I'm using Python 3. Sorry for wasting everyone's time!